# Chrome Extension: trying to use require.js in content scripts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

**What I'm trying to fix:**

I'm experiencing `content.js:179 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` on the line where I call `var wordnet =require('../node_modules/wordnet');` And to overcome this error, I'm trying to use [require.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html#domReady). However, I'm not sure how to include this script in my content script.
I have already included require.js in my manifest.json:

```
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": [
    "https://www.reddit.com/r/design_critiques/*"
  ],
  "run_at": "document_end",
  "js": [
    "scripts/content.js",
    "scripts/require.js"
  ],
  "css": [
    "stylesheets/content.css"
  ]
}]
```

Comment: Switch the two scripts so that `require.js` is loaded first inside the page.

Comment: Ha! that did the trick! Thanks @PredatorIWD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this question turned out to be trivial: switch the scripts to load `require.js` before `content.js`:

```
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": [
    "https://www.reddit.com/r/design_critiques/*"
  ],
  "run_at": "document_end",
  "js": [
    "scripts/require.js",
    "scripts/content.js"
  ],
  "css": [
    "stylesheets/content.css"
  ]
}]
```